# simple stack in c with linked list and pointers

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, stack

I have to implement a simple stack in C but it has been a few years since I wrote something in C so am a bit rusty.

I have a struct defined in the .h file like this, `typedef struct _my_stack my_stack_t;`
as well as a function that initializes the stack `my_stack_t* my_stack_new();` and a push function `void my_stack_push(my_stack_t *s, void *data);`

in the .c file i defined the stack and the init function like this

```
struct _my_stack{
    void* data;
    struct _my_stack* next;
};
my_stack_t* my_stack_new(){
    my_stack_t* mystack = NULL;
    return mystack;
};
```

then i defined the push function like this:

```
void my_stack_push(my_stack_t *s, void *data){
    my_stack_t* mystack = (my_stack_t*)malloc(sizeof(my_stack_t));
    mystack->data = data;
    mystack->next = s;
    s=mystack;
};
```

however the push does not seem to work, is i get segmentation faults when trying to access the data of the element i pushed.
so why does it not work.
in the push it allocated the space for the stack item and puts the pointer to the data in the data variable. and it takes the pointer to the current head of the stack and puts it in the next var and then makes the stackhead point the current element.

note: the .h file is given, so i have to take functions are they are declared there.

Comment: Don't forget that function arguments in C are passed *by value*. That means they are copied, and modifications to the local copy inside the function will be lost once the function ends. You should to do some research about *emulating pass by reference in C*.

Comment: When you googled `implementing linked list in C`, what did you find?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude funny as it is, stack API based on linked lists doesn't actually require passing by reference :)

Comment: You need to show us the code that calls `my_stack_push`, the problem might be there. Please read this: [mcve]

Comment: @SergeyA `s=mystack;` in `my_stack_push` is pointless.

Comment: @Jabberwocky but that's because the API is wrong. A push function should accept current pointer and return new pointer.

Comment: @SergeyA Or use separate "list" and "node" structures.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that changes to `s` inside `my_stack_push` doesn't change the value of the variable used as argument when `my_stack_push` was called.

If your code is:

```
int main()
{
    ...
    my_stack_t* s = my_stack_new();
    my_stack_push(s, some_data_pointer);
    ...
}
```

then the `s` in `main` is a different variable than `s` inside `my_stack_push`. The only relation they have is that `s` inside `my_stack_push` is **initialized with a copy** of the value of `s` in `main`.

Consequently - changing the value of `s` inside `my_stack_push` does **not** change the value of `s` in `main`.

To change the variable outside the function you need to pass the function a pointer to that variable.

So what you want is:

```
void my_stack_push(my_stack_t **s, void *data){   // Notice the extra *
    my_stack_t* mystack = malloc(sizeof(my_stack_t));
    mystack->data = data;
    mystack->next = *s;   // Notice the extra *
    *s=mystack;           // Notice the extra *
};
```

And use it like:

```
my_stack_t* s = my_stack_new();
my_stack_push(&s, some_data_pointer);  // Notice the &
```

Answer (score 1):

> however the push does not seem to work, is i get segmentation faults when trying to access the data of the element i pushed. so why does it not work

probably you do something like that :

```
my_stack_t* mystack;

my_stack_push(mystack, ..adata..);
```

supposing *mystack* is modified by `my_stack_push`, this is not the case because in `my_stack_push` the form `s=mystack;` just modify the *local* variable

You have two ways to change that

1) give the address of the var in parameter rather than its value

```
my_stack_t* mystack = NULL;

my_stack_push(&mystack, ..adata..);
```

and of course

```
void my_stack_push(my_stack_t **s, void *data){
    my_stack_t* mystack = (my_stack_t*)malloc(sizeof(my_stack_t));
    mystack->data = data;
    mystack->next = *s;
    *s=mystack;
};
```

2) return the new cell

```
my_stack_t* mystack = NULL;

mystack = my_stack_push(mystack, ..adata..);
```

and of course

```
my_stack_t * my_stack_push(my_stack_t *s, void *data){
    my_stack_t* mystack = (my_stack_t*)malloc(sizeof(my_stack_t));
    mystack->data = data;
    mystack->next = s;
    return mystack;
};
```

Comment: @SergeyA I do intermediate saves, I hate when I lost all by a false manipulation, you read fast the answers ^^